# Android user interface on xml

Tags: android

Hello i am trying to create a android app and I need some help to start, i would like to know if there is some software which i can use to create all the buttons and other stuff connected with the user interface on xml .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to auto- design the desired layout, u can drag the view in layout editor for the ease , so that the xml declaration is half done.

Then you explicitly need to design and align the layout item as required.

You can follow the link here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then it provides the drag and drop options for creating UI in xml.

You can also take the help of [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) software to generate the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

Assuming that you already have Eclipse IDE, navigate to:
`/src/res/layout/main.xml`

and switch to `Graphical Layout` (you can find it just below your XML code editor. Note that you might need to adjust something else, so you need to go back to XML editor anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Only 2 development softwares are popularly used for android development these are as follows,

Google Eclipse IDE & Intellij Android Studio

above both these softwares are good for android application development.
i personally suggest you to prefer Eclipse IDE for development of android application that will help you to provide all possible solutions